# Use of undeclared crate or module

Tags: rust

I am getting the following error when I use `serde` to read a json from a file:

`Failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module serde_json`

here's the code:

```
use serde::Deserialize;


fn main() {
  let file = fs::File::open("./feed.json")
      .expect("file should open read only");
  let reader = BufReader::new(file);
  let json = serde_json::from_reader(reader)
      .expect("file should have FirstName key");
  let feed_url = json.get("2.0")
      .expect("file should have FirstName key");
  println!("{}", reedFeed(feed_url));
}
```

[Here](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/de/fn.from_reader.html)'s the doc on this function.
I am on ubuntu and using intellij as my ide. What am I missing here?

Comment: What's in your Cargo.toml?

Comment: Have you added `serde_json` to your `Cargo.toml` (along with `serde`)?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all the elements of a [mcve]. (Including your `Cargo.toml`)

Answer (score 5):

As @Dogbert said, add `serde = "1.0.136"` and `serde_json = "1.0.79"` to the end of your `Cargo.toml` (under "[dependencies]").
This will tell cargo to download the dependencies on the next `cargo run` and use it from that point on.

Comment: >Also, you need to add use serde_json; at the top of your code.< this part is not true

Comment: @IvanC: Thanks for the correction! I removed that line.

Comment: under "[dependencies]", not "[dev-dependencies]"

Comment: @Russo: on my browser it already says "dependencies", does it show as "dev-dependencies" in your browser?

Comment: ahhh... no I was just emphasizing because I did not notice that